# Creating a list from input using while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop

Im new to python and trying to convert input to a list and I am required to use a while loop but I keep getting an EOF error.

```
def get_grades():
    value = float(input('Enter grade:\n'))
    grades = []
    while value > 0:
        grades.append(value)
        value = float(input('Enter grade:\n'))
    return(get_grades)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to return the list of grades from that function, so you could change `return(get_grades)` to `return grades` (no need for the parentheses). When you have `return(get_grades)` you're actually returning the address that the `get_grades` function is stored at in memory.

So with that change the code looks like:

```
def get_grades():
    value = float(input('Enter grade:\n'))
    grades = []
    while value > 0:
        grades.append(value)
        value = float(input('Enter grade:\n'))
    return grades

print(get_grades())
```

You can run it with the following inputs and see those printed out to the console:

```
Enter grade:
30
Enter grade:
40
Enter grade:
50
Enter grade:
0
[30.0, 40.0, 50.0]
```